# How to convert all Enum.map values to strings?

Tags: elixir, ecto

How can I convert all `Enum.map` values to strings?

```
result =
  Enum.map(
    from(Scheme, where: ^whitelisted_params) |> limit(^query_limit) |> Repo.all(),
    fn elem ->
      elem |> Map.from_struct() |> Map.delete(:__meta__)
    end
  )
```

In the Scheme, there are `string`, `bool` and `int` types

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: the result value contain mixed int, string, bool and i want to convert all of it to string

Comment: So you are trying to convert all to string. But what is the question?

Comment: how to do it mister

Comment: OK, I rephrased your question as a question.

Comment: `Kernel.inspect/1` is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

Use the **to_string/1** function

Here is an array with integer, float, string and boolean values converted to string

```elixir
iex> [1, 1.0, "str", true] |> Enum.map(& to_string/1)
["1", "1.0", "str", "true"]
```

Comment: protocol String.Chars not implemented for {:address, "jl. haji"}. This protocol is implemented for: Atom, BitString, Date, DateTime, Decimal, Float, Integer, List, Mariaex.Query, NaiveDateTime, Postgrex.Copy, Postgrex.Query, Time, URI, Version, Version.Requirement

Comment: Are you using it in Phoenix? Looks like you have nested structures. Then you can do the conversions in your view file. What is the reason you are trying to convert them to string?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [`Kernel.inspect/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#inspect/2). Unlike `IO.inspect/2`, it returns the string rather than printing it as a side-effect.

```elixir
iex> Enum.map(["I'm a string", true, 42], &inspect/1)
["\"I'm a string\"", "true", "42"]
```

Although as possibly hinted by S.B.'s comment, your question sounds like an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I think you should write in your question why you are trying to convert to strings. If you explain the larger task you're trying to accomplish, somebody may be able to provide a better solution.

Comment: yeah just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are interested on get a map instead of a list or KeywrodList:

```elixir
iex> %{k1: 12, k2: 3.1415, k3: :an_atom} |> Map.new(fn {k, v} -> {k, to_string(v)} end)
%{k1: "12", k2: "3.1415", k3: "an_atom"}
```